# OnLongClickListener Errors

Tags: java, android, android-studio, syntax-error, onlongclicklistener

[image][image: Java Codes]

Help me I got an error when it comes to this part of the code im trying to create a drag and drop application

Codes:

```
    code1.setOnClickListener(longClickListener);
    code2.setOnClickListener(longClickListener);
}

View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        ClipData data= ClipData.newPlainText("","");
        View.DragShadowBuilder myShadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        v.startDrag(data,myShadowBuilder,v,0);
        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: You are putting longClickListener in a setOnClickListener. That's why you are getting error. Check my answer below, your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of:

```
code1.setOnClickListener(longClickListener);
code2.setOnClickListener(longClickListener);
```

You need to use:

```
code1.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
code2.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
```

Details about it in the [Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html)

Comment: @xhen if the Answer helps...mark it as correct by clicking the tick sign next to the answer...thankx